# How to pass text file data from one class to another

Tags: java

I'm trying to create a program that reads a text file and then outputs stats about the text file. I'm getting stuck on the beginning. In this assignment, we were told that we just need to read using the scanner in one class and the create "tokens" to be passed and used in other classes for calculations. I'm not entirely sure how to do that. This is my code so far for reading the file inside one class:

```
private String s;
public void analyzeBookText(Scanner input) {
   while(input.hasNext()) {
       input.useDelimiter(".|!|?");
       s = input.next();
       if(input.next().equals("$$$END$$$")) {
           break;
       }
   }
}
public String getS() {
    return s;
}
```

So I have string s be just one sentence. Then I'm trying to access s in a different class by creating a String instance variable and this constructor:

```
 public SentenceTally() {
    BookMain sentence = new BookMain();
        s = sentence.getS();
}
```

However, when I try to use s in other methods I get a stackoverflow error. How can I properly use data from the scanner in one class in methods for another class? Thanks!

Comment: `if(input.next() == "$$$END$$$") {` -- not good.  Don't compare Strings using `==` or `!=`. Use the `equals(...)` or the `equalsIgnoreCase(...)` method instead. Understand that `==` checks if the two *object references* are the same which is not what you're interested in. The methods on the other hand check if the two Strings have the same characters in the same order, and that's what matters here.

Comment: Also that if block gets a String from input and deletes it, wasting it. Don't do that but instead put it into a local String variable, then do the if block, then assign s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are half way there. Next, what you need is to read the text file and store it into an array. Since your school mentioned tokens, you may read line by line from the text file, then split each line (if your data file only has one line, then just tokenize that one line of data) into tokens (represented as array):

```
String[] tokens = line.split(delimiter);
```

You may need to convert the tokens to int array or double array first being using it for calculations.

Pass tokens array as an argument to your other methods for calculation:

```
public void calculate(int[] tokens){
    //your calculations in Java
}
```

To pass your data to other classes:

```
BookMain book = new BookMain();  
book.analyzeFile(yourScanner);

SomeClass c = new SomeClass();
c.calculate(book.getTokens());        //create a getter for tokens in BookMain first
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I'm trying to access the String data in a different class than where it was read, how would I transfer it?